# Visual Basic Auto Scroll with RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio, scroll, multiline

I want my Richtextbox to be always at the bottom and "autoscroll" to the end. 
I found this with some google searches:

```
     Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged
        RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.TextLength
        RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()

     End Sub
```

This seems to work but as the text updates it jumps to the top of the box and with another update to the bottom. Can someone help me out? Or is there a better method to keep the Textbox at the end?

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code kind of works- What I would suggest to solve your initial problem is to alter your code slightly and add

```
RichTextBox1.SuspendLayout()
```

at the beginning of your sub, and

```
RichTextBox1.ResumeLayout()
```

at the end.

However, if your cursor isn't on the last line and you type something, the character will appear at the cursor before moving to the end of the text. I'm guessing you don't want that behaviour - In which case you should add the code into a `KeyPress` event.

There are several possible behaviours. Do you want to be able to type anywhere, or only at the end of the text? Or just to place the cursor at the end under certain circumstances - for example when the RichTextBox is first populated with a bunch of text? Or maybe something else.

The simplest solution would be for the user just to press the keys Ctrl-End. That doesnt need any code at all.